# Tensorflow Resnet example: Is the bottleneck size wrong?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

The following code is from the Tensorflow Resnet example at https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/learn/resnet.py:

```
# Create the bottleneck groups, each of which contains `num_blocks`
# bottleneck groups.
for group_i, group in enumerate(groups):
    for block_i in range(group.num_blocks):
      name = 'group_%d/block_%d' % (group_i, block_i)

      # 1x1 convolution responsible for reducing dimension
      with tf.variable_scope(name + '/conv_in'):
       conv = tf.layers.conv2d(
        net,
        filters=group.num_filters,
        kernel_size=1,
        padding='valid',
        activation=tf.nn.relu)
    conv = tf.layers.batch_normalization(conv, training=training)

  with tf.variable_scope(name + '/conv_bottleneck'):
    conv = tf.layers.conv2d(
        conv,
        filters=group.bottleneck_size,
        kernel_size=3,
        padding='same',
        activation=tf.nn.relu)
    conv = tf.layers.batch_normalization(conv, training=training)

  # 1x1 convolution responsible for restoring dimension
  with tf.variable_scope(name + '/conv_out'):
    input_dim = net.get_shape()[-1].value
    conv = tf.layers.conv2d(
        conv,
        filters=input_dim,
        kernel_size=1,
        padding='valid',
        activation=tf.nn.relu)
    conv = tf.layers.batch_normalization(conv, training=training)

  # shortcut connections that turn the network into its counterpart
  # residual function (identity shortcut)
  net = conv + net
```

This piece of code runs for each block, with a given output and bottleneck dimension. These blocks are defined as:

```
  # Configurations for each bottleneck group.
  BottleneckGroup = namedtuple('BottleneckGroup',
                           ['num_blocks', 'num_filters', 'bottleneck_size'])
  groups = [
       BottleneckGroup(3, 128, 32), BottleneckGroup(3, 256, 64),
       BottleneckGroup(3, 512, 128), BottleneckGroup(3, 1024, 256)
  ]
```

In the common practice, as far as I know, these so-called bottleneck layers of the ResNets first reduce the input channel count with 1x1 kernels, applies higher order (3x3) convolutions in that reduced channel size and then restores to the input channel size back with a final 1x1 convolutional layer, as given in the original ResNet paper:

[image]

But in the Tensorflow example, the first 1x1 layer uses the block output size, not the bottleneck size, hence no meaningful channel reduction is made. Is the Tensorflow example really wrong here, or am I missing something?

Comment: The 3x3 layer still outputs the bottleneck size, there is some computation reduction but not as much as in the original paper. Not sure if this is wrong, but the reason of using bottleneck layers is the "concerns on the training time". For info, [another implementation from tf.slim](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/slim/nets/resnet_v1.py#L113) is the same as in the original paper.